# How to parse (and access) array of object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

I would like to parse and print a JSON composed by an array of objects passed to JavaScript from PHP through GET request, I tried the "standard way" but my code doesn't work (but works with simple JSON)

PHP:

```
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i<count($id); $i++){
    $array[]=new Field($id[$i], $en[$i], $it[$i]);
}
print_r($array); // IT WORKS PROPERLY

ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

JavaScript:

```
$.get("../GetFieldsForLanguage.php", function(data, status){
var str = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(str);
var form = JSON.parse(str);
var count = Object.keys(data).length;
for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
{
   $('#it').append(
      $('<tr />').append(
         $('<th />', {text: form[i].**WHAT**}),
         $('<th />').append(
            $('<input />', { name: form[i]., placeholder: form[i]. type: 'text' })
         )
      )
   )
}
```

And that's an example of how JSON is printed by echo:

```
[
 {"ev":"Description","iv":"...","id":"1"},
 {"ev":"Surface","iv":"...","id":"2"},
 {"ev":"Locals","iv":"...","id":"3"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is what you're after, example.

```
$.getJSON( "../GetFieldsForLanguage.php", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    var count = data.length;
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });
    $( "<ul/>", {
       "class": "my-new-list",
       html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- Why `JSON.stringify(data)` and `JSON.parse(str)` as `data` is already a JSON Object ?. There is no mean to stringify and parse again.
- Your response `data` is an `array of objects` as per the JSON you posted in OP. So, why Object.keys(data) ?
- Instead of `var count = Object.keys(data).length` it should be `var count = data.length` as data is an `array` not an `JS object`.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b6v2scx3/)

```js
var data = [{"ev":"Description","iv":"...","id":"1"},{"ev":"Surface","iv":"...","id":"2"},{"ev":"Locals","iv":"...","id":"3"}];

var count = data.length;
for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
{
$('#it').append(
   $('<tr />').append(
      $('<th />', {text: data[i].ev}),
      $('<th />').append(
        $('<input />', { name: data[i].ev, placeholder: data[i].iv, type: 'text' })
      )
    )
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="it">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always an `array`:

```js
var data = [
    {"ev":"Description","iv":"...","id":"1"},
    {"ev":"Surface"    ,"iv":"...","id":"2"},
    {"ev":"Locals"     ,"iv":"...","id":"3"}
];

console.log(data);

data.forEach(function (value) { 
    $('#it').append(
        $('<tr />').append(
            $('<th />', {text: value.ev}),
            $('<th />').append(
                $('<input />', { name: value.id, placeholder: value.iv })
            )
        )
    )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="it"></div>
```